# Iterating resultset Iterator in mule esb

Tags: java, groovy, mule, anypoint-studio

Hi am trying to pick records from database am getting the output as `org.mule.module.db.internal.result.resultset.ResultSetIterator@6f6d8fa8`
I wanted to traverse through the records for some other purpose I tried foreach message processor but inside for each also am getting as resultset and not map.I am expecting map or list is there a way to convert from result set iterator to map or list in mule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ResultSetIterator](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/91f36d45a0b0744cd36f2c3037618aa7f5a655b1/modules/db/src/main/java/org/mule/module/db/internal/result/resultset/ResultSetIterator.java) implements Java's [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). When iterating the iterator returns a `Map<String, Object>`.

This means you can use it the Java way:

```
ResultSetIterator iter = ...

while(iter.hasNext()) {
    Map foo = iter.next()
    /* Do something with foo */
}
```

Or, you can use the methods added by Groovy's [GDK](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Iterator.html), such as `each(Closure)`:

```
ResultSetIterator iter = ...

iter.each {
   /* Do something with 'it' variable, which would be a Map */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you uncheck the "streaming" option in the database component the returning object will be a list of maps.. Then you could iterate over the maps you want to see! :)

Answer (score -1):

Mule comes with the build in component `<foreach>`. It's allows you to iterate throught the seelcted result set from the database.

```
<foreach>
    <logger level="INFO" message="Entry map: #[payload]" />
</foreach>
```

Comment: Read the question again